# Which web server I need to install and how?

Tags: apache, iis, windows-7, webserver

I would like to install a web server on my Window 7. I [found](http://devoracles.com/installing-apache-22-on-windows-7-beta) instructions for installation of Apache on Windows 7. But as far as I understood I need to have the administrator permission to do so. Am I right?

I also though that it is probably a good idea to install another web server (like a native one) on my Windows 7. I thought it should be easier to do + apache is not designed for Window 7. Driven by these ideas I found some information about Microsoft [IIS server](http://digitizor.com/2009/02/20/how-to-install-microsoft-iis-server-on-windows-7/). But than it is written that I need to have the Professional edition or the Ultimate edition of Windows 7. Does anybody know how can I check my edition? I do not know which edition I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Start -> Right Click `Computer` and then select Properties. In the Window you will see the version of the windows.

Apache will work for Windows 7. I use [easyphp](http://www.easyphp.org/) in my Windows 7 Ultimate Machine. yes you need Admin access to install software.

Also Check out

[Installing IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 Home Premium, Home Basic, or Home Starter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731911.aspx)

Some Editions come installed with iis (I think). To check just Do the following

```
Run -> inetmgr
```

or. `Control Panel -? Administrative Tools -> Internet Information Services.`